# Getting rid of half a String in Android

Tags: java

Need help with getting rid of half of a string in android studio. The string is:

```
final String strOrigin = String.valueOf(origin).trim();
```

The value that is returned is;

"Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=[27.993726079654873,-26.14686805145815]}"

I want to be left with only the numbers of that, in the String. I have tried;

```
strOrigin.replace("Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=", "");
```

But it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `strOrigin.replaceAll("\\D+","");` if you want to use regrex to get just digits of a string.

Comment: Isn't there an option to just get the coordinates? Something like `final String origin = origin.getCoordinates().toString();` ?

Comment: What is `origin`?

Comment: @TheWanderer    Origin is the variable for a Mapbox co-ordinate, and i want to save those co-ordinates in a database.

Comment: That's not very helpful. What is the Origin object and where is it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java strings are immutable. You must assign the result to a new string:

```
String strResult = strOrigin.replace("Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=", "");
```

Comment: This approach is very inflexible and surely prone to failure i.e. what if `bbox` is not null?

Answer (score 3):

Make your life simpler by just getting the coordinates:

```
final String strOigin = origin.coordinates().stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",","{","}"));
```

Or, if you're stuck on java 7:

```
final String strOigin = String.format(
    "{%s,%s}",
    String.valueOf(origin.latitude()), 
    String.valueOf(origin.longitude())
);
```

Comment: Stream is a Java 8 feature. Most Android apps are using Java 7, unless they're only targeting Nougat and later.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot that `replace()` returns the result and you must assign it to a string:

```
String strOrigin = "Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=[27.993726079654873,-26.14686805145815]}";
String str = strOrigin
        .replace("Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=", "")
        .replace("}","");
System.out.println(str);
```

will print:

```
[27.993726079654873,-26.14686805145815]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
    String s="blabla coordinates=[27.993726079654873,-26.14686805145815] ";
    String requiredString = s.substring(s.indexOf("[") + 1, s.indexOf("]"));
```

will print:

```
27.993726079654873,-26.14686805145815
```

Than you can cast it to `double` or `latlong` format

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **regular expressions**, they allow you to define more flexible search patterns. In your example you only find the coordinates if the rest of the string matches the pattern exactly, but if you happen to get some other value of bbox, or even extra space it will not work. **This** will always match everything between a pair of square brackets:

```
String c = origin.replaceAll(".+?(\\[.+?\\]).+?", "$1");
```

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html